# Search by PK slower compared to other index column

Tags: spring-boot, hibernate, spring-data-jpa

I am working on preparing some benchmarks for a database structure where I compare the usage of an UUID for the primary key vs a sequential ID. Based on different articles, I was expecting that the UUID to be slower for insertion and selection. Most other articles that treated this topic had simple objects, but I have a more complex structure with many one-to-many relations, so I decided to try my luck with my own benchmarks.

I had a structure like this:

```
class A {
   UUID/Long id;
   String name;
   UUID uuid; // only when PK is Long
   List<B> b; // one to many, 5 items in the list
   List<C> c; // one to many, 5 items in the list
}

class B {
    UUID/Long id;
    String name;
    List<D> d; // one to many, 5 items
}

// C and D just have an ID and a name;
```

As a note, I do have different tables and different entities for UUID and Long PK. Also, for the Long PK, I have an additional UUID column for class A that gets populated with a random UUID. Also, added an index for the UUID column since I will be measuring search by this column as well.

I made an app in **Spring Boot**, with **Spring Data** for the JPA implementation and **MS SQL** for the database.

I started to populate the database in both cases (with UUID PK and Long PK) with 2000 items and did not see any major differences in timings between the two tests.

Next, I did a search by UUID. For the first scenario, the UUID is also the PK. For the second scenario, the PK is a Long, with the UUID a separate column with an index. It was way faster.

Next, only where the PK is a long, I did a search by the PK and here is where I had a big surprise. The search was almost as slow as for UUID PK.

Here are some results (timings are in ms):

```
Benchmark                               UUID PK    Long PK
2000 Product Insertion                  368910     354643
800 items search by UUID, 1 iteration   2582       908
800 items search by UUID, 3 iterations  5853       1981
800 items search by ID, 1 iteration     -          1794
800 items search by ID, 3 iterations    -          4421

500 Products insertion                  38940      39852
200 items search by UUID, 1 iteration   492        167
200 items search by UUID, 5 iterations  1840       763
200 items search by UUID, 10 iterations 3450       1472
200 items search by ID, 1 iteration     -          448
200 items search by ID, 5 iterations    -          2254
200 items search by ID, 10 iterations   -          4588
```

I was expecting that when using a long PK, everything to be faster, but that is not always the case. I based my original assumptions mostly on these two articles:

- https://www.mssqltips.com/sqlservertip/5105/sql-server-performance-comparison-int-versus-guid/
- https://tomharrisonjr.com/uuid-or-guid-as-primary-keys-be-careful-7b2aa3dcb439

I can accept that even with UUID PK, if we exclude DB fragmentation, timing to be similar. What baffles me is why search by the UUID column is faster than the search by PK when the PK is Long.

Even when show_sql was turned on, I could not see any differences (no select *, which I know can cause slowness). I also tried to eliminate other factors, but results were consistent.

Am I doing something wrong? Am I not understanding something properly? Does it not really matter that the PK is a UUID, even with a more complex structure and many items?

Comment: I guess you might see performance drops when doing big joins, but the dominating factor when doing a search by a single value usually is everything else (network, planner, etc.) so that will probably not show a performance issue. Another possible problem might be the size of indexes etc. which then affects page and cpu caches.

Comment: @ChristianBeikov I was thinking the same, but the conditions were the same, especially since I ran the tests on my local machine, so network was not a problem. I also ran it multiple times, multiple iterations, and still got the same results. As I said, I could accept that PK UUID and PK Long are the same, but what bugs me is that search by UUID with PK Long is faster than search by Long ID. This, for the exact same entries and same search count/items.

Comment: Are you sure you are using the same kind of index?

Comment: To be fair, I did not check the index type. I assumed that the PK would have the fastest one. Will investigate this as well when I have the time. Thanks

Comment: I don't know how SQL Server works internally, but if you use a CPU that can handle 128 bit values efficiently and if SQL Server has optimizations for that, the only difference you might see is that big joins are slightly slower due to rows being wider in memory, but I doubt that you will actually notice the difference in a real world use case. There are other performance benefits though e.g. building up a B-Tree for a sequence can be way cheaper than for UUIDs so you will probably see fewer page splits with a sequence.

Comment: Yes, the page splits are indeed better and that is why in the end we will be using sequential IDs for big tables. I was just curious as to why the anomaly in search. Thanks for taking the time to look into this as well.

Answer (score 0):

It just so happens that someone blogged about their analysis of the bigint vs. uuid performance on PostgreSQL recently which might apply to SQL Server as well: https://www.cybertec-postgresql.com/en/uuid-serial-or-identity-columns-for-postgresql-auto-generated-primary-keys/

Comment: Even though the article is good, it does not provide me with any new information. I knew everything written there. What so far I don't truly understand (but I do have one guess) is why the search by LONG ID was slower compared to the search for the UUID, even though the Long ID was the PK while the UUID was a secondary column. I assume that it has to do with the index type between the two.

Comment: I think that on SQL Server the PK index might be represented as index-organized-table which might have worse performance than a secondary index, but I really don't know enough about SQL Server to give you a good answer here.